# How do I show individual points of a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, t-test

I have the df1:

```
              Name        Y_N FIPS  score1 score2
 1:        Alabama         0    1   2633      8
 2:         Alaska         0    2    382      1
 3:        Arizona         1    4   2695     41
 4:       Arkansas         1    5   2039     10
 5:     California         1    6  27813    524
 6:       Colorado         0    8   8609    133
 7:    Connecticut         1    9   5390    111
 8:       Delaware         0   10    858      3
 9:        Florida         1   12  14172    215
10:        Georgia         1   13   9847    308
11:         Hawaii         0   15    720      0
12:          Idaho         1   16    845      7
```

I would like to perform a T-test to see if `score1` differs based on `Y_N`. I would then like to plot these two against each other. I have made a boxplot that looks like: [image]

Instead I want my graph to look like except with confidence bars: [image]I want to now change from a boxplot to a plot that shows all of the individual points and then a mean horizontal line with 95% confidence intervals. How is this done? I would also like to add the text of the p-value in a corner of the graph.

I might try:

```
text(x = max(df1$Y_N)+1, 
     y = min(df1$score1)+20000, 
     labels = paste0(
                     "\np-value = ",
                     round(coef_lm[2,4],5),            
     pos = 4)
```

But I realize that `coef_lm[2,4],5` are the test-statistics from a linear model. How do I access the outputs of a t-test?

Comment: Now that you've provided your very nice paint vison for the figure, please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you added that extra point in your code. But on your original data, you might use `ggplot2` and `ggpubr`.

**Edit**
Now more like your paint drawing.

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x = as.factor(Y_N), y = score1)) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.1)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "errorbar",  aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), col = "red", width = 0.5) +
  stat_compare_means(method="t.test") + 
  xlab("Group") + ylab("Score 1")
```

[image]

**Original Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", 
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho"), class = "factor"), 
    Y_N = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    FIPS = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 
    16L), score1 = c(2633L, 382L, 2695L, 2039L, 27813L, 8609L, 
    5390L, 858L, 14172L, 9847L, 720L, 845L), score2 = c(8L, 1L, 
    41L, 10L, 524L, 133L, 111L, 3L, 215L, 308L, 0L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:", "7:", "8:", "9:", "10:", "11:", 
"12:"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! I was wondering if I wanted to t-test not based on the Y_N column, but instead based on if the `score2` column is greater than 100, how could I do that?

Comment: Add the argument `col = "red"` to line 3.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, without to install `ggpubr` you can calculate p value outside of `ggplot2` and use `annotate` function to add the pvalue into the plot:

```r
pval <- t.test(score1~Y_N,data = df)$p.value

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(Y_N), y = score1, fill = as.factor(Y_N), color = as.factor(Y_N)))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3, color = "black", outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_jitter(show.legend = FALSE)+
  annotate(geom = "text", label = paste("p.value: ",round(pval,3)), x = 1.5, y = max(df$score1)*0.9)
```

[image]

**EDIT: Without a boxplot**

Alternatively to the boxplot, if you want to have individual points and a bar representing the mean, you can first calculate the mean per group in a ne dataset (here I'm using `dplyr` package for doing it):

```r
library(dplyr)
Mean_df <- df %>% group_by(Y_N) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(score1))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    Y_N  Mean
  <int> <dbl>
1     0 2640.
2     1 8972.
```

Then, you can plot individual points using `geom_jitter` and the mean using `geom_errobar` by calling the new dataset `Mean_df`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(Y_N), y = score1))+
  geom_jitter(show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.2)+
  geom_errorbar(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = Mean_df, 
                aes(x = as.factor(Y_N),ymin = Mean, ymax = Mean),
                color = "red",width = 0.2)+
  annotate(geom = "text", label = paste("p.value: ",round(pval,3)), 
           x = 1.5, y = max(df$score1)*0.9)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(Name = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho"), Y_N = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), FIPS = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L), score1 = c(2633L, 382L, 2695L, 2039L, 
27813L, 8609L, 5390L, 858L, 14172L, 9847L, 720L, 845L), score2 = c(8L, 
1L, 41L, 10L, 524L, 133L, 111L, 3L, 215L, 308L, 0L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks for help! How can I do this without the boxplot?

Comment: @Evan, I edited my answer. Let me know if it is what you are looking for

Comment: How do I change the x-axis label from saying "as.factor", and how do I get the error bars?

Comment: You should take a look at @IanCampbell's answer. it answer all your questions. You should validate his/her answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd <- structure(list(Name = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas",  "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida",  "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho"), Y_N = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,  1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), FIPS = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L,  10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L), score1 = c(2633L, 382L, 2695L, 2039L,  27813L, 8609L, 5390L, 858L, 14172L, 9847L, 720L, 845L), score2 = c(8L,  1L, 41L, 10L, 524L, 133L, 111L, 3L, 215L, 308L, 0L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA,  -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

## frame
boxplot(score1 ~ Y_N, dd, border = NA)

## 95% ci, medians
sp <- split(dd$score1, dd$Y_N)
sapply(seq_along(sp), function(ii) {
  x <- sp[[ii]]
  arrows(ii, quantile(x, 0.025), ii, quantile(x, 0.975), code = 3, angle = 90, length = 0.1)
  segments(ii - 0.05, median(x), ii + 0.05, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
})

points(dd$Y_N + 1, dd$score1, col = dd$Y_N + 1)

## t-test
lbl <- sprintf('p = %s', format.pval(t.test(score1 ~ Y_N, dd)$p.value, digits = 2))
mtext(lbl, at = par('usr')[2], adj = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of your questions relates to how to access the t.test statistics. Here's an answer to that question. Suppose you have that type of data:

```
set.seed(12)
YN <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)    
score1 <- sample(500:1500, 100, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(YN, score1)
```

And suppose further that you run and store the t.test like this:

```
test <- tapply(df$score1, df$YN, t.test)
```

Then you can access the test statistics bit by bit like this, illustrated here for the factor level `0`:

```
test$`0`$p.value #   p-value
test$`0`$conf.int #  confidence interval
test$`0`$estimate #  estimate
test$`0`$statistic # statistic
```

Now obviously you will not want to do it manually bit by bit but in a more autmated and systematic way. This is how you can achieve this:

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(test, function(x) c(
  statistic = unname(x$statistic),
  ci = unname(x$conf.int),
  est = unname(x$estimate),
  pval = unname(x$p.value))))
```

The ouput is this:

```
  statistic      ci1      ci2      est         pval
0  22.31155 837.3901 1003.263 920.3265 5.484012e-27
1  22.91558 870.5426 1037.810 954.1765 3.543693e-28
```

Comment: Interesting use of `tapply`. However, why do you have two p.values ?  And how do you get the p.value of the difference between two groups (which is what the OP is looking for I guess) ? Does `t.test(....)$p.value` not simpler?